# How to open number keypad automatically for an input field on a tablet?

Tags: html, angular, keypad

I am working on an Angular2 application. For an input field, a numeric keypad should be opened automatically. I have tried

```
<input formControlName="UserNumber" name="UserNumber" 
                    inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" type="number">
```

I also tried with input type="text" with no luck. It just opens the alpha-numeric keypad. Can anyone suggest me the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Use type= "tel":

```
<input .... type="tel">
```

it will open the numeric keyboard .